# What are TaskRecords in the dumpsys

Tags: android, activity-stack

I have the following activity stack from the dumpsys:

```
Running activities (most recent first):
TaskRecord{4307f828 #56 A com.demo.proj U 0}
  Run #4: ActivityRecord{425a6838 com.demo.proj/com.demo.proj.Activity2}
  Run #3: ActivityRecord{427dc860 com.demo.proj/com.demo.proj.Activity1}
  Run #2: ActivityRecord{420cba18 com.demo.proj/com.demo.proj.MainActivity}
TaskRecord{430341d0 #2 A com.lge.launcher2 U 0}
  Run #1: ActivityRecord{41e0af68 com.lge.launcher2/.Launcher}
TaskRecord{44e26ce0 #18 A com.lge.appbox.client U 0}
  Run #0: ActivityRecord{41e9dbe8 com.lge.appbox.client/.AppBoxClient}
```

What do the different TaskRecords mean? Why is there not just one stack? I haven't found any other explanations on SO or the docs regarding this. Does anyone happen to know?